# Window is load but url not change in jquery?

Tags: jquery

How can i call event between pages in **jQuery**?

Explanation,I have two pages home and `datalist`.When i go home to `datalist` url still home but browser loading.After browser loading,url change to `datalist` and show me the `datalist`.I just want to add loading screen between home and `datalist`.

But how can i call this event for add loading screen.I also try `window.load()` event in `datalist` but `window.load()` event fire after url change to `datalist`.

**Update:**

[image]

Url is not change position.But Browser is loading.

[image]

In `datalist` page,Many thing to do in `document.ready()` `event.Window.load()` event in `datalist` is fire after url change to (`localhost:63011/DataList`).I want to add loading `screen()` when i go `datalist` and until `datalist` ready.

Comment: We need more information. Please add some example code.

Comment: @ppasler,Please see update question.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
<div class="loading_screen"></div> // add css for full screen with z-index
```

add this code after  tag and after this code write this javascript code

```
<script>setTimeout(function(){ $('.loading_screen').hide()}, 5000)</script>
```

set timeout with your loading time it will work like when page load this loading screen load until your timeout not over

Comment: ,Thank for your answer,But u misunderstanding about my question.I always have for loading screen.but i dont know to put this where.I added this function in load() event.But loading screen show me after url change.Pls read my question.I appreciate your answer.

Comment: add this code after body tag  <script>
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.loading').fadeOut('fast');
}, 8000);
</script>

<div class="loading">Loading&#8230;</div> in your first screen will load

Comment: Thank again.I mean which page to put this code.home or datalist?

Comment: if you want to show details after url change to details so put this code  in details page

Comment: use window.location.search to find url and try with if else condition to show loading screen